# Magento 2 can't translate modal's title

Tags: magento2, modal-popup, js-translation

I'm using a modal to show conditions for subscribing to a newsletter list. But I'm having trouble translating the title when initializing the modal inside a `phtml` file.

The modal opens normally, but seems the `mage/translate` component doesn't successfully translate the title.

If I use `title: <?php echo _('Test string') ?>` it will translate normally, but shouldn't using `$.mage.__('Test string')` also work?

This is what I have in `phtml`:

```
    <script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function ($, modal) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            modalClass: 'newsletter-conditions-modal',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            title: $.mage.__('Test string'),
            buttons: []
        };
        $(function () {
            $('.newsletter-conditions').on('click',function() {
                $(".newsletter-conditions-content").modal(options).modal('openModal');
            })
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And this is what I have in my `csv` translate file:

`Test string,Test string 2,module,Magento_Ui`

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

Came here for the same issue. 
But found out you will need to use php to get it translated.

`title: "<?php echo __('Test string')?>"`

Comment: It's not working for me.